# R programming, import data

Tags: sql, r, import, error-handling, rstudio

I have been working on the code on Rstudio :

````
 ```{r list tables}
    library(data.world)
    # Datasets are referenced by their URL or path
    dataset_key <- "https://data.world/ryanes/liverpool-english-league-matches"
    # List tables available for SQL queries
    tables_qry <- data.world::qry_sql("SELECT * FROM Tables")
    tables_qry
    tables_df <- data.world::query(tables_qry,dataset_key)
    # See what is in it
    tables_df$tableName
````

But when i run this chunk, it gives me an error saying:

```
No encoding supplied: defaulting to UTF-8.
 Show Traceback
Error in dwapi::sql(dataset = dataset, query = qry$query_string, 
 query_params = qry$params) :
```

please let me know how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I’m one of the engineers at data.world and can help you out . This could be a problem with your data.world authorization token ( e.g expired token ) . Can you try to get a new token via https://data.world/settings/advanced and re-set it in your current R session ?
e.g

  `saved_cfg <- data.world::save_config(<YOUR NEW API TOKEN>)
  data.world::set_config(saved_cfg)`

If the problem persists, please reply with a full stacktrace  along with your current d.w lib version  e.g

`packageVersion("data.world")`

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. Thanks for the help.